# Fetching an attribute from the same field using the id of same field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

static controller:

```
def show
  @product = ProductAttribute.where('value = ?', helpers.value_check(:prod_id))
end

module StaticsHelper
  def value_check(id)
    @product = Product.find_by(id: id)
    return @product.value
  end   
end
```

I'm trying to fetch a value attribute from the product model. This value attribute is the primary key used between the models "product" and "product_attributes".

index.html.erb of static view:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <li>
    <%=link_to product.name, statics_show_path(prod_id: product.id)%>
  </li>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "New Product", statics_new_path %>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead using a helper to get a record in such way, you could do it directly in the controller:

```
product_value = Product.find(params[:prod_id])
@product = ProductAttribute.where('prod_id = ?', product_value.value)
```

As you're sending the `prod_id` through the link to, it'd give you a valid value to get such Product record and its value attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer.

Comment: Showing /home/quitalizner/Workspace/testing/app/views/statics/show.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `value' for #<ProductAttribute::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f1055e1c550>
Did you mean?  values

Extracted source (around line #4):

2
3
4
              

 


<h4><%=@product_attribute.name%></h4>
<h4><%=@product_attribute.value%></h4>

Rails.root: /home/quitalizner/Workspace/testing

Comment: help me out please

Comment: You have an ActiveRecordRelationship @gundergobi, that means, since you're using `where`, you're getting many records, not just one, you should have to iterate over that `@product` object.